# Is it possible to implement Karel similar to Stanford Karel in JavaScript with Node.js and Electron.js?

Tags: node.js, electron

I’d like to implement JavaScript version of Karel for desktop environment. I want something similar to https://pypi.org/project/stanfordkarel/ , which is for Python.

Like Stanford's Karel for Python or Java, I don't need a new programming language and JavaScript will be used to write Karel programs. Something like this:

```
// HelloKarel.js 
import {karel} from "karel"

function main() {
    move()
    move()
    turnRight()
}

function turnRight() {
    turnLeft()
    turnLeft()
    turnLeft()
}
```

In order to run `HelloKarel.js`

```
npm run HelloKarel.js
```

This should pop up the Karel program window for HelloKarel and, when **Start** button is clicked,
the main function will be executed. I also want the folder structure be as simple as possible.
Ideally, without any configuration file and only the Karel program files.

```
|-chapter1
    |-HelloKarel.js
    |-HurdleJumping.js
    etc
```

Would it be possible to implement the above requirements using Node.js and Electron.js? If yes, I'd like to know how I can achieve the goals.

Lastly, I must admit that the question is vague, partly because I have very little experience with Node.js and Electron.js. Every examples I could find require main project folder (app) containing config file, html file, and a few *.js files so that Electron can be started and execute the entry point. I've looked around a few implementations like these:

https://github.com/telnicky/kareljs?tab=readme-ov-file
(This one requires opening OS browser and editing in browser)
https://github.com/omegaup/karel.js/tree/main
(This is a complete app, including code editor, and the code is interpreted by the app's built-in language interpreters)

These implementations are quite different from what I need.

Maybe I can ask something like this:

How can I create Node.js module which can do the following?

1. The module itself is executable Electron app which display a rectangle on the canvas and expose functions to manipulate the rectangle, such as changing color, position etc. I understand this how I should go about this part.
2. In a new `.js` file, using the module, I'd like to be able to program to manipulate the rectangle on the canvas. I understand how this part can be done if I have access to the above module. But I want/need to prohibit that. (What I want is something like OOP inheritnace, where I can just extends a class and change the program's behaviour.)
3. When the file is executed, the rectangle behave as programmed in the file. (So, again, what I want is something like a runnable class inherited all functionalities such as displaying a window, rectangle, and functions to change the rectangle).
4. Any config required should be hidden in the module itself, and should not be exposed to the user, who program the rectangle's behavior. UI events generated by the app should be able to call the functions in the new file.

I think I understand what Electron can do for my case. I do know JavaScript and CSS to a certain degree as well, though not goot at them. I am pretty sure I can look around and set up a simple project that can do 1 and 2 above (which I think I've done before) using Konvajs or p5.js or any decent 2D library. The part where  I stuck is 3 and 4 above. I'll read Node and Electron to see if I can find/figure out the way I want.

I've asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77945079/how-to-change-the-behavior-of-an-electron-app-from-external-javascript-file) again making my question more specific and clear with the example code I've been trying.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be impossible to implement something like this? Please have a look at [ask]; I feel like this question is too vague for SO. Have you actually tried something? Have you had a look around if someone tried something like this before, if there's any library that could help you with this?

Comment: Thanks for your advice @AlexanderLeithner. I have added more to explain my requirements. The last part should clarify the vagueness somewhat, I hope.