# How to change the behavior of an Electron app via external JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

This is the project structure I would like to have.

[image]

`kareljs` folder is an Electron app and if I run

`npm start`

inside that folder, a window pop up and `run` method of karel.js is executed when the button `Run Karel`  is clicked.

`./eg01/hello_karel.js`, `./eg02/pick_newspaper.js` etc., are where I program Karel using the methods provided by `./kareljs/karel/karel.js` module. Running the program must bring up the same window above, but when `Run Karel` button clicked, the `run` method in these Karel program files should be called, instead of the default one.
(What I need is sort of method overriding in Java. Here I override `run` method via new js file).

And to run the program, I should just be able to

`node ./eg01/hello_karel.js`

Or

`node hello_karel.js`

if I am in `eg01` folder. Ideally, no config file should be required to run these programs. I mean inside `eg01`, `eg02` folders. Of course, Karel is for newbies, and for them, the simpler the better it is.

What are the possible mechanisms to achieve my requirements?

Code:

```
// main.js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron/main')

const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: { 
        contextIsolation: false,
        nodeIntegration: true
       },
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'"
    />
    <meta
      http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'"
    />
    <title>Hello from Electron renderer!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello from Electron renderer ... !</h1>
    <p></p>
    <p id="info"></p>
    <p><button class="run">Run Karel</button></p>
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>  
  </body>  
  
</html>
```

```
// karel.js
const move = () => {
    alert("Karel moves one step forward!")
};

const turnLeft = () => {
    alert("Kare turns left!")
};

const pickBeeper = () => {
    alert("Karel picks a beeper!")
};

const putBeeper = () => {
    alert("Karel puts a beeper!")
};

const run = () => {
    alert("This is the default run method!")
}
    

// Updated: to write user_defined.js file with content from hello_karel.js
const { exec,spawn } = require("child_process");
const fs  = require("fs");
var path = require('path');

const start_karel = (file_name) => {
    console.log(__dirname)
    console.log("The .js file executed: " + file_name)
    var user_script;
    fs.readFile(file_name, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log(data);
        var user_defined = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'user_defined.js');
        var user_script = data.replace(/start_karel\(__filename\)/g, "")
        fs.writeFile(user_defined, user_script, 'utf-8', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
    var index_html = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'index.html');
    
    /*
    fs.readFile(index_html, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log("about to replace...")
        console.log(data);
        var replaced = data.replace(/default/g, 'user')

        console.log("replaced " + replaced)

        fs.writeFile(index_html, replaced, 'utf-8', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
        console.log("done replace...")

      });
    */
    
    exec("cd ../kareljs && ./node_modules/.bin/electron main.js " + file_name, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    });
    
    /*
    spawn("cd ../kareljs && ./node_modules/.bin/electron main.js " + file_name, {
        stdio: 'inherit',
        shell: true
    })
    */


}

module.exports =  {move, turnLeft, putBeeper, pickBeeper, run, start_karel};
```

```
//renderer.js
const {move, turnLeft, putBeeper, pickBeeper, run} = require('./karel/karel')

const btn = document.querySelector('.run')
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {run()})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-electron-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^28.2.1"
  }
}
```

```
//hello_karel.js
const {move, turnLeft, putBeeper, pickBeeper, run, start_karel} = require('../kareljs/karel/karel')

function turnRight() {
    turnLeft()
    turnLeft()
    turnLeft()
}

start_karel()
```

Also have GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/pyiso80/kareljs).

Update: I can now start the app just by running

```
node hello_karel.js
```

Still need to figure out how to change the behavior of the `run` method which is called via the button click. (Please see the update in `karel.js` above.)

Comment: If I can pass the file name (`hello_karel.js` above) to the app somehow, there should be a way to call the `run` method in the file dynamically.

Comment: Fortunately, I think I can achieve what I want soon. But sadly, I haven't gotten any response from SO and Electron Discord Channel.

Comment: After running `node hello_karel.js`, the files contents can be read from `main.js`. After this, I should be able to share the content (of `hello_karel.js` in this case) to renderer process. Or may be I just extract the run and other user defined functions , and then write them to `index.html`, like `<script>user defined scripts<\script>`

Comment: Now, at least I can achieve the requirement above. From the `karel.js` module, I just write the `hello_karel.js` content to a new file `user_defined.js` file, which is included in `index.html` file with `<script src="./user_defined.js"> </script> `. I need to remove `start_karel(__filename)` from `hello_karel.js`, otherwise, infinite Electron app start one after another without stopping (I was thinking only one more app will get started when the script is loaded in `index.html`). Don't know why. I don't know what problem the current method can have. But at least, it give the result I want.

Comment: I would really really appreciate if anyone can suggest a better approach which I should try.

Answer (score 1):

Using IPC to pass function references from the main process to the renderer? Something like this:

```js
// main.js

ipcMain.on('runFunction', (e, fn) => {
  if (fn === 'helloKarel') {
    let helloKarelFn = require('./eg01/hello_karel.js').run;
    e.sender.send('runFunction', helloKarelFn);
  }
});
```

```js
// renderer.js
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

const btn = document.querySelector(".run");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    ipcRenderer.send('sendFunction', 'helloKarel')
});

ipcRenderer.on('runFunction', (e, fn) => {
  fn();
});
```

Comment: Hi, I am really glad to receive the first answer. I'll test and get back to you. Seems to be better than what I did. @normalcepalin

Comment: How `start_karel(__filename, yourRunFn)` call would pass `yourRunFn` to `renderer.js` is a little more complex than what we think I guess. Because in Electron, main and renderer are separate processes, so IPC has to be used to share data between the two. @normalcepalin

Comment: For sure, data can be shared between main and renderer. But, I still can't find a simple working example yet, there are many examples online though. That's why I tried writing to `user_defined.js`.

Comment: Other than `yourRunFn`, we will also have to share other user defined functions, such as `turnRight()`. Sort of combining `karel.js` and `hello_karel.js` into a single module or loading `hello_karel.js` module dynamically. For Python, there is a good example to do that explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path). JS must be capable of that as well. Just I don't know how.

Comment: I think `import()` function can be used to load `hello_karel.js` on the fly. Just have to pass the correct file path to renderer process. This again goes back to IPC. The file name has to be passed from main to renderer.